# What is the easiest way to convert xml to html?

Tags: java, html, xml

What is the easiest way to convert xml to html? I have xml file coming to java class. There is few tags with content. I need to convert them into html. Is there any tools or libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML -> HTML is possible using [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-HTML-Output-Method)

[Here's an article on XSTL processing in Java](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/java_xslt_ch5/index.html)

Comment: How to do this from java class?

Answer (score 1):

Use XSLT to convert your XML into the desired XHTML.

You will probably find that the XHTML gets a lot simpler if you use CSS.

Comment: Note that the output doesn't have to be XHTML, though. Usually an XSLT processor is able to emit HTML as well.